# Como acceder a la cadena de conexion

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ado.net, dotnetcore

tengo una aplicación con .net core en capas:

capa de datos, capa de negocio, Api

Como podría acceder a la cadena de conexión desde la capa de datos, si la cadena se encuentra en el archivo appsettings.json ? del proyecto Api

Anteriomente con .Net framework lo hacia asi:
string cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaconxion"].ConnectionString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu proyecto principal es el proyecto Api, puedes acceder a IConfiguration gracias a la Inyeccion de Dependencias. basta con definirlo en el constructor de  la clase donde lo necesites.

Por ejemplo

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace MyApp.Services //Acceder al connection string desde la capa de servicios
{
    public class ExampleService : IExampleService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ExampleService(IConfiguration configuration)// Pasas IConfiguration en tu constructor mediante DI
        {
            _configuration = configuration
        }

        public async Task SomeMethodAsync()
        {
             var connectionString =  _configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionName"); //Obtienes el valor de tu string de conexion
         ...
        }
    }
}
```